# Using setTimeout with window.close() not work after using setTimeout with window.open()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have two setTimeout after another. One to open a webpage in the window and another to close the window after a predetermine amount of time. However, after using setTimeout to open a webpage, the next setTimeout that close the window does not work. The setTimeout with windows.close by itself works fine.

I and trying to opening a window with a message; then open a website in the window after a predetermine amount of time, and then close the window after a couple of more seconds has passed.  Here is my function to do this:

```
function showNews() {
    news = window.open("", "NewsWindow", "width=900, height=700");
    news.document.write("<p>The 'NewsWindow' will only appearing for 3 seconds.</p>");
    tmot = setTimeout(function(){news.window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_self')}, 2000);
    tmot = setTimeout(function(){news.window.close()}, 5000);
}
```

I tried running on both Chrome and IE and both browser would only execute one of the setTimeout and not the other. Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried this in Firefox (27) and IE (11), and it works fine.

Comment: Note that you lose your reference to the first timeout when you set the return of the second to `tmot`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll better reopen it using parent window with the same parameters :

```
function showNews() {
    news = window.open("", "NewsWindow", "width=900, height=700");
    news.document.write("<p>The 'NewsWindow' will only appearing for 3 seconds.</p>");
    tmot = setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', "NewsWindow")},2000);
    tmot = setTimeout(function(){news.close()}, 5000);
}
```

Not try on IE, i don't have it.

Comment: I tried this in chrome here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/u6EaX/
And it did not work. 
Once the window opens a new site the original window can no longer control it, at least on Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! That was the trick! (removing "news." from the setTimeout lines.)  Now to figure out why that is the case...

Comment: Just figured out why.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers forbid you from closing the window once it loads a website.

The following works:

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="showNews()">Show News</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
var myWindow;

function showNews()
{
    myWindow = window.open("","myWindow","width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    //tmot = setTimeout(function(){myWindow.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_self')}, 2000);
    tmot = setTimeout(function(){myWindow.close();}, 5000);
}

</script>
```

**DEMO:**

[View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gae2M/)

But if we uncomment the line where we load yahoo.com, it doesn't work anymore:

[View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WMkS7/)

---

**What to do?**

You could try using a hack, something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" id="show-news">Show News</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#show-news").click(function() {

    myWindow = window.open('','myWindow', "width=200, height=200");
    setTimeout(function() {
        myWindow.window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/", "_self");
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        myWindow.window.open('', '_self', ''); 
        myWindow.window.close();       
    }, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution after a whole day trying the same thing.
My window.open occured in some jQuery success result and I thougt first it was because I could not propagate the myWindow  var from "success" result to main DOM.

In fact it's only that javascript does not accept to manipulate any window once a new content has been loaded (I mean URL).
But it can be hacked still, since it seems javascript ONLY refuse manipulation if there is a NEW content.
So if you reload your window with exactly the same content, then it suddendly becomes manipulable.

So somewhere in my code (even in a function) I open the window (wherever it is), with no need to set it in var.

```
window.open('myURL','WindowName', "width=200, height=200");
```

Then wen I decide to close the window (wether it is a SetTimeOut or any trigger), I just have first to reload the window with exactly the same URL and same name , (and this time with a var set). And now I can magically close it.

```
var windo = window.open('myURL','WindowName', "width=200, height=200");
windo.close();
```

Don't ask me why it works. It does.

(I guess it's because it's not a new window not new content for javascript, so rules are respected.)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in JSFiddle on Chrome.

The timeout is, in fact, firing. 
The problem is that certain browsers do not allow you to close a window using javascript.There are bugs that prevent it - specifically that the browser won't let code from one website close a window that is opened to a different website. See the comment below for a better explanation.

When I tried this in Chrome the setTimeout method fired, but the window did not close. I tested it by calling the 'alert' method rather than the news.window.close() method.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Once the window is loaded with content from a different domain, the browser probably considers it to be off limits.

Comment: You're right - I shouldn't have said 'bug'. Sometimes I use the term 'but' when I really mean "the code didn't do what I wanted it to do, but rather what it was designed to do". I'm editing the answer.